# How do you draw the next graphics examples of limits in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, diagrams

How do you draw the next graphics examples of limits in LaTeX?

[image: Examples 1. Graphics of limits]
[image: Examples 2. Graphics of limits]

Comment: All of those examples could be reproduced with reasonable effort in LaTeX. However, at the moment, the question is much too broad to be answerable. Could you edit your question to make it more concrete, and provide some information on the research you've done so far?

Comment: Seconding Jake's comment, questions of this generality are too broad, questions without any sample code or any indication of coding effort by the original poster are off topic.

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is you're asking? Do you want someone to create all those graphics for you? What do you mean by "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources." in this context?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to draw graphics in `LaTeX`, you could use TikZ & PGF and the manual can be found here: http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

PSTricks documentation can be found here: https://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=doc/docs

`PGFplots` manual can be found here: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf

Thanks to Alexander for pointing out an updated version of the `PGFplots` manual.

Per texenthusiat comment, you could also use `texdoc pgf pgfplots pstricks` in `TeXLive` for the manuals.

---

To draw a parabola, you can do (PGFplots):

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[blue] plot[domain = -2:4, samples = 100] (x, 3 * x * x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### [image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] plot[domain = -2:4, samples = 100] ({\x}, {3 * (\x)^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not going to draw every picture for you but here is the parabola with two methods.

---

Here is the first limit example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale = 5]
  \clip (1.25, 8.75) rectangle (2.8, 15);
  \draw[-latex] (1.5, 9) -- (1.5, 15);
  \draw[-latex] (1.5, 9) -- (2.75, 9);

  \foreach \y in {9, 10, ..., 14}{
    \node[left, font = \tiny] at (1.5, \y) {\y};
    \draw (1.5, \y) -- +(.02, 0);
  }

  \foreach \x in {1.6, 1.8, ..., 2.4}{
    \node[below, font = \tiny] at (\x, 9) {\x};
    \draw (\x, 9) -- +(0, .08);
  }
  \draw[blue] plot[domain = 1.5:2.25, samples = 100] ({\x}, {3 *(\x)^2});
  \draw (1.5, 12.05) -- (2.4, 12.05) node[above, blue, font = \tiny, pos = .2]
  {\(y = 12.05\)};
  \draw (1.5, 11.95) -- (2.4, 11.95) node[below, blue, font = \tiny, pos = .2]
  {\(y = 11.95\)};

  \node[font = \tiny, right, blue] at (2.2, 14) {\(y = 3x^2\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Because I was bored and didn't want to do my own work:

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[xscale = 2]                                                    
  %\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);                                                       

  \draw[-latex, name path = xline] (-.5, 0) -- (2, 0) node[right, font = \tiny]
  {x};
  \draw[-latex] (0, -.2) -- (0, 4.5) node[right, font = \tiny] {y};
  \draw (1, .05) -- (1, -.05) node[below, font = \tiny] {1};
  \draw[-stealth] (-.6, 3.9) -- (-.6, 3.1) node[pos = -.15, font = \tiny]
  {$f(x)$};
  \draw[-stealth] (-.6, 2.1) -- (-.6, 2.9) node[pos = -.15, font = \tiny]
  {$f(x)$};
  \draw[-stealth] (.6, -.3) -- (.9, -.3) node[pos = -.2, font = \tiny]
  {$x$};
  \draw[-stealth] (1.4, -.3) -- (1.1, -.3) node[pos = -.2, font = \tiny]
  {$x$};

  \foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4}{
    \draw (.05, \y) -- (-.05, \y) node[left, font = \tiny] {\y};
  }

  \draw[blue!40, name path = para] plot[domain = -.1:1.3, samples = 100]
  ({\x}, {2 * (\x)^2 + 1});
  \draw[blue!40, fill = white] (1, 3) circle[radius = .02cm];

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \foreach \yl/\i in {2.1/1, 2.4/2, 2.55/3, 2.8/4, 2.9/5}{

      \filldraw[black] (0, \yl) circle[radius = .02cm];

      \path[name path global = \i] (0, \yl) -- +(2, 0);
      \path[name intersections = {of = para and \i, by = P\i}];

      \draw (0, \yl) -- (P\i);

      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path[name path global = Pxl\i] (P\i) -- +(0, -5);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

      \path[name intersections = {of = xline and Pxl\i, by = Xl\i}];

      \draw (P\i) -- (Xl\i);

      \filldraw[black] (Xl\i) circle[radius = .02cm];
    }

    \foreach \yu/\i in {4.1/6, 3.6/7, 3.45/8, 3.2/9, 3.1/10}{
      \filldraw[black] (0, \yu) circle[radius = .02cm];

      \path[name path global = \i] (0, \yu) -- +(2, 0);
      \path[name intersections = {of = para and \i, by = P\i}];

      \draw (0, \yu) -- (P\i);

      \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path[name path global = Pxu\i] (P\i) -- +(0, -5);
      \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

      \path[name intersections = {of = xline and Pxu\i, by = Xu\i}];

      \draw (P\i) -- (Xu\i);

      \filldraw[black] (Xu\i) circle[radius = .02cm];
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: single line tweak(TeX Live) to manuals: `texdoc pgf pgfplots pstricks`